# WebGL blacklist detection

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, youtube, webgl

I am unable to view WebGL content in Chrome but the examples of Javascript WebGL detection I can find (e.g. using Three.js) report that my browser supports WebGL.

For example, on https://get.webgl.org/ the box does not spin but I get the 'Your browser supports WebGL' message. Similarly, Youtube 360 degree videos do not work either; both work in FF and Edge.

To get the WebGL content to work I can enable Chrome setting: *Override software rendering list - Overrides the built-in software rendering list and enables GPU acceleration on unsupported system configurations. #ignore-gpu-blacklist*

I am working on the assumption that although Chrome supports WebGL, my GPU is blacklisted?

For example this code reports I can view WebGL content, even though I can't:

```
function webgl_support() {
try{
   var canvas = document.createElement( 'canvas' );
   return !! window.WebGLRenderingContext && (
   canvas.getContext( 'webgl' ) || canvas.getContext( 'experimental-webgl' )      );
 }catch( e ) { return false; }
 };
```

**My question: how can I accurately detect if WebGL content will actually render. For example, I would like to hide WebGL content on my sites if the user will be unable to view them.**

Comment: Consider the possibility that your personal situation is a statistical outlier, you might be even running into a temporary Chrome bug. Detecting WebGL the proper way will cover 99.9% of all users, it might be overkill to put a whole lot of effort into a hacky solution that might get obsolete soon.

Comment: Check to see if your GPU is on the current blacklist: https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/gpu/config/software_rendering_list_json.cc

Comment: and/or check chrome://gpu

Comment: Myself and a colleague both having same problem, despite both being on completely different, less than 2 year old, expensive laptops. I'm not happy putting out a solution on a fairly high traffic website that doesn't even work for the developers. 

Just to clarify, I'm not interested in working out why it doesn't work (I imagine my GPU is blacklisted), I need to find a way to degrade gracefully for users who's GPU is blacklisted.

Comment: The way you describe it it sounds like you can actually see the box but it doesn't spin on get.webgl.org? If that's the case there is either a browser extension blocking it or a bug in chrome(probably requestAnimationFrame related) that needs to be fixed([please file it here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list) and precisely specify the specs of the machines you're using). If your GPU were blacklisted `getContext` would return `null` and you would not see any cube. Blacklisted behavior is no different from "not supported" to javascript, when you get a context its supposed to work

Comment: Hi @LJ, thanks for the input. That's correct, I can see the box but it doesn't spin. My colleague has the exact same problem but we're on completely different laptops so a browser extension might explain it.